# How to install mongoose driver on nodejs?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have just started working with nodejs. I am a java script newbie. I have nodejs and mongodb running on my ubuntu. Now I downloaded the mongoose driver. Do I install it using npm or just copy the mongoose folder that has js files into nodejs lib folder? Also links to any tutorials to start working with this driver will help me a lot.

Regards,
Lalith

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an extensive walkthrough:
http://dailyjs.com/2011/02/07/node-tutorial-12/

Seems to be very recent.

According to LearnBoost's GitHub site, the suggested method for installation is to use npm.

https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/

`$ npm install mongoose`

Comment: Thanks gates.. I was wondering how to do this in windows using Cygwin.. I will do npm install as you say on ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install mongoose on your system or on your node package file  by using command

```
npm install mongoose
```